Invalid Foreign Key in my ruby on rails app
I am trying to add guests to my event and delete them as per requirement. But i get this error in when clicking the delete button:
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey in GuestsController#destroy
SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

Ill add my code:
  # DELETE /guests/1 or /guests/1.json
  def destroy
    @guest.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      # format.html { redirect_to guests_url, notice: "Guest was successfully destroyed." }
      format.html { redirect_to event_guests_path(@event), notice: "Guest was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end


and here is my schema.rb:
ActiveRecord::Schema[7.0].define(version: 2024_03_24_054147) do
  create_table "email_services", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "to"
    t.string "subject"
    t.text "body"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.datetime "sent_at"
    t.datetime "committed_at"
    t.integer "event_id"
    t.integer "guest_id"
    t.integer "email_template_id"
    t.index ["event_id"], name: "index_email_services_on_event_id"
    t.index ["guest_id"], name: "index_email_services_on_guest_id"
  end

  create_table "email_templates", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", null: false
    t.text "subject"
    t.text "body", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "events", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.string "address"
    t.string "description"
    t.datetime "datetime"
    t.datetime "last_modified"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "event_avatar"
    t.string "event_box_office"
    t.integer "user_id", default: 1
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_events_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "guests", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.string "affiliation"
    t.string "category"
    t.integer "alloted_seats"
    t.integer "commited_seats"
    t.integer "guest_commited"
    t.boolean "status"
    t.integer "event_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "email"
    t.string "rsvp_link"
    t.index ["event_id"], name: "index_guests_on_event_id"
  end

  create_table "seats", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "category"
    t.integer "total_count"
    t.integer "event_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["event_id"], name: "index_seats_on_event_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "provider"
    t.string "uid"
    t.string "name"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "email_services", "events"
  add_foreign_key "email_services", "guests"
  add_foreign_key "events", "users"
  add_foreign_key "guests", "events"
  add_foreign_key "seats", "events"
end


I am creating an event management application using Ruby on Rails and I am trying to add guests to my event and delete them as per requirement. But i get a error "InvalidForeignKey " in when clicking the delete button
This is my guest.rb
class Guest < ApplicationRecord
  require 'roo'

  belongs_to :event, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :event
  has_many :referrals, dependent: :destroy
  
  before_create :generate_rsvp_link
  
  # ===================================
  # required to have to pass Rspec tests
  validates :first_name, presence: true
  validates :last_name, presence: true
  # Removed the email validation
  validates :affiliation, presence: true
  validates :category, presence: true
  validates :event_id, presence: true
  validates :alloted_seats, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }
  validates :commited_seats, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }
  validates :guest_commited, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }
  validate :allocated_seats_not_exceed_total

  def self.new_guest(attributes = {})
    puts "Creating guest with data: first_name=#{attributes[:first_name]}, last_name=#{attributes[:last_name]}, event_id=#{attributes[:event_id]}"
    guest = Guest.new(attributes) #creates new guest
    guest#return guest
  end
  
  def checked_only_if_booked
    return if (booked || !checked)
    errors.add(:checked, "can't be true if guest hasn't booked")
  end

  def full_name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end 
  
  
  def allocated_seats_not_exceed_total
    if category.present? && event.present?
      seat = event.seats.find_by(category: category)
      if seat.present?
        existing_guest = event.guests.find_by(id: self.id)
        if existing_guest.present?
          total_allocated_seats = event.guests.where(category: category).sum(:alloted_seats) - existing_guest.alloted_seats.to_i
          total_commited_seats = event.guests.where(category: category).sum(:commited_seats) - existing_guest.commited_seats.to_i
        else
          total_allocated_seats = event.guests.where(category: category).sum(:alloted_seats)
          total_commited_seats = event.guests.where(category: category).sum(:commited_seats)
        end
        remaining_allocated_seats = [0, seat.total_count - total_allocated_seats].max
        remaining_committed_seats = [0, total_allocated_seats + alloted_seats.to_i - total_commited_seats].max

        puts event.guests.where(category: category).sum(:alloted_seats)
        puts total_allocated_seats
        puts alloted_seats.to_i
        puts total_commited_seats
    
        if (total_allocated_seats + alloted_seats.to_i) > seat.total_count
          errors.add(:alloted_seats, "cannot exceed the total allocated seats (#{remaining_allocated_seats} remaining) for the category #{category}")
        end
    
        if (total_commited_seats + commited_seats.to_i) > total_allocated_seats + alloted_seats.to_i
          errors.add(:commited_seats, "cannot exceed the total allocated seats (#{remaining_committed_seats} remaining) for the category #{category}")
        end
      end
    end
    
  end


  # ===================================

  private

  def generate_rsvp_link
    self.rsvp_link = SecureRandom.hex(20) # You can adjust the length as needed
  end
end

and this is my event.rb:
class Event < ApplicationRecord
mount_uploader :event_avatar, AvatarUploader
mount_uploader :event_box_office, SpreadsheetUploader
belongs_to :user 
# <!--===================-->
# <!--to add nested scaffold-->
has_many :seats , dependent: :destroy
has_many :guests , dependent: :destroy
has_many :email_services, dependent: :destroy
has_many :referrals, dependent: :destroy
# <!--===================-->
def calculate_seating_summary(event_id)
    seating_summary = []

    Seat.where(event_id: event_id).each do |seat|
      guests_in_category = Guest.where(event_id: event_id, category: seat.category)
      committed_seats = guests_in_category.sum(:commited_seats)
      allocated_seats = guests_in_category.sum(:alloted_seats)
      total_seats = seat.total_count

      seating_summary << {
        category: seat.category,
        guests_count: guests_in_category.count,
        committed_seats: committed_seats,
        allocated_seats: allocated_seats,
        total_seats: total_seats
      }
    end

    seating_summary
  end

end

Please add the models to the question
